# Is there a setting that I can change/add to VSCode on Mac so that anytime I open a new blank file it defaults to javaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm learning my first software language (JavaScript) and I like to use otherwise blank VSCode files/tabs as a 'scratchpad' which, after use, I don't care to save (since I copy/paste out the good bits and mentally benefit from the blank space). Alternatively is there a way to configure a hotkey-combo that will open a file that is already saved as .js regardless of what directory I'm working in? (Bonus points if that file deletes its contents when closed and/or when its 'refreshed' ...if its possible to reload a file in VSCode with a hotkey..?)

Currently on macOS Mojave 10.14.6, VSCode 1.37.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by using Advanced New File package in your VS Code. Following are some few steps to be followed for creating new files easily with your default requirements.

a) Press the Shortcut Cmd+Alt+N or run the Files: Advanced New File command.
b) Right click in the explorer menu and choose 'Advanced New File'.
c) Enter a relative file path or stick with the default. If you have a file open it will guess the extension based on the current extension.

Other than default extension setting, you can also apply some other default behaviors in your **settings.json**. Following changes you can made in the same.

```
{
  "newFile.defaultBaseFileName": "newFile",
  "newFile.relativeTo": "file",
  "newFile.defaultFileExtension": ".js",
  "newFile.rootDirectory": "~",
  "newFile.showPathRelativeTo": "root",
}
```

This is how you can give default new filename, default path, default extension and even default root directory.